# "Segmentation fault (core dumped)" when trying to spawn ubuntu core vm?

Tags: chromium, ubuntu-core, kiosk

### Question

Why am I getting:

```
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

when trying to spawn ubuntu core vm with:

```
sudo ubuntu-core-vm init edge
```

or

```
sudo ubuntu-core-vm
```

?

### System info:

```
$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 16.04.6 LTS
Release:    16.04
Codename:   xenial

$ uname -a
Linux gm-ultra 4.15.0-48-generic #51~16.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Fri Apr 5 12:01:12 UTC 2019 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

### Update (adding strace)

```
execve("/snap/bin/ubuntu-core-vm", ["ubuntu-core-vm", "init", "edge"], [/* 28 vars */]) = 0
...
access("/etc/ld.so.nohwcap", F_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
...
access("/etc/ld.so.preload", R_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
...
access("/etc/ld.so.nohwcap", F_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
...
access("/etc/ld.so.nohwcap", F_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
...
newfstatat(AT_FDCWD, "/meta/snap.yaml", 0xc42009e858, 0) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
...
newfstatat(AT_FDCWD, "/snap/core/current/usr/share/locale-langpack/POSIX/LC_MESSAGES/snappy.mo", 0xc42009e9f8, 0) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
...
newfstatat(AT_FDCWD, "/snap/core/current/usr/share/locale/POSIX/LC_MESSAGES/snappy.mo", 0xc42009eac8, 0) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
...
newfstatat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/share/locale-langpack/POSIX/LC_MESSAGES/snappy.mo", 0xc42009eb98, 0) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
...
newfstatat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/share/locale/POSIX/LC_MESSAGES/snappy.mo", 0xc42009ec68, 0) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
...
newfstatat(AT_FDCWD, "/snap/core/current/usr/share/locale-langpack/POSIX/LC_MESSAGES/snappy.mo", 0xc42009ed38, 0) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
...
newfstatat(AT_FDCWD, "/snap/core/current/usr/share/locale/POSIX/LC_MESSAGES/snappy.mo", 0xc42009ee08, 0) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
...
newfstatat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/share/locale-langpack/POSIX/LC_MESSAGES/snappy.mo", 0xc42009eed8, 0) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
...
newfstatat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/share/locale/POSIX/LC_MESSAGES/snappy.mo", 0xc42009efa8, 0) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
...
openat(AT_FDCWD, "", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
...
newfstatat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/local/sbin/apparmor_parser", 0xc4201b5148, 0) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
...
newfstatat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/local/bin/apparmor_parser", 0xc4201b5218, 0) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
...
newfstatat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/sbin/apparmor_parser", 0xc4201b52e8, 0) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
...
newfstatat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/bin/apparmor_parser", 0xc4201b53b8, 0) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
...
newfstatat(AT_FDCWD, "/snap/snapd/current/usr/bin/snap", 0xc4201b5628, 0) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
...
access("/etc/ld.so.nohwcap", F_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
...
access("/etc/ld.so.preload", R_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
...
access("/etc/ld.so.nohwcap", F_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
...
access("/etc/ld.so.nohwcap", F_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
...
newfstatat(AT_FDCWD, "/meta/snap.yaml", 0xc42009e5e8, 0) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
...
newfstatat(AT_FDCWD, "/snap/core/current/usr/share/locale-langpack/POSIX/LC_MESSAGES/snappy.mo", 0xc42009e788, 0) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
...
newfstatat(AT_FDCWD, "/snap/core/current/usr/share/locale/POSIX/LC_MESSAGES/snappy.mo", 0xc42009e858, 0) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
...
newfstatat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/share/locale-langpack/POSIX/LC_MESSAGES/snappy.mo", 0xc42009e928, 0) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
...
newfstatat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/share/locale/POSIX/LC_MESSAGES/snappy.mo", 0xc42009e9f8, 0) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
...
newfstatat(AT_FDCWD, "/snap/core/current/usr/share/locale-langpack/POSIX/LC_MESSAGES/snappy.mo", 0xc42009eac8, 0) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
...
newfstatat(AT_FDCWD, "/snap/core/current/usr/share/locale/POSIX/LC_MESSAGES/snappy.mo", 0xc42009eb98, 0) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
...
newfstatat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/share/locale-langpack/POSIX/LC_MESSAGES/snappy.mo", 0xc42009ec68, 0) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
...
newfstatat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/share/locale/POSIX/LC_MESSAGES/snappy.mo", 0xc42009ed38, 0) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
...
openat(AT_FDCWD, "", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
...
newfstatat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/local/sbin/apparmor_parser", 0xc420210e08, 0) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
...
newfstatat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/local/bin/apparmor_parser", 0xc420210ed8, 0) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
...
newfstatat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/sbin/apparmor_parser", 0xc420210fa8, 0) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
...
newfstatat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/bin/apparmor_parser", 0xc420211078, 0) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
...
newfstatat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/local/sbin/apparmor_parser", 0xc420211488, 0) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
...
newfstatat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/local/bin/apparmor_parser", 0xc420211558, 0) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
...
newfstatat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/sbin/apparmor_parser", 0xc420211628, 0) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
...
newfstatat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/bin/apparmor_parser", 0xc4202116f8, 0) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
...
newfstatat(AT_FDCWD, "/snap/ubuntu-core-vm/7/meta/hooks", 0xc420280858, 0) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
...
connect(5, {sa_family=AF_LOCAL, sun_path="/var/run/nscd/socket"}, 110) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
...
connect(5, {sa_family=AF_LOCAL, sun_path="/var/run/nscd/socket"}, 110) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
...
access("/etc/ld.so.nohwcap", F_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
...
access("/etc/ld.so.nohwcap", F_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
...
access("/etc/ld.so.nohwcap", F_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
...
access("/etc/ld.so.nohwcap", F_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
...
newfstatat(AT_FDCWD, "/run/user/0", 0xc420280c68, 0) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
...
access("/etc/ld.so.nohwcap", F_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
...
access("/etc/ld.so.preload", R_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
...
access("/etc/ld.so.nohwcap", F_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
...
access("/etc/ld.so.nohwcap", F_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
...
access("/etc/ld.so.nohwcap", F_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
...
access("/etc/ld.so.nohwcap", F_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
...
access("/meta/snap.yaml", F_OK)         = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
...
open("/run/udev/tags/snap_ubuntu-core-vm_ubuntu-core-vm", O_RDONLY|O_NONBLOCK|O_DIRECTORY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
...
newfstatat(AT_FDCWD, "/snap/core/current/usr/share/locale-langpack/POSIX/LC_MESSAGES/snappy.mo", 0xc42007e9f8, 0) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
...
newfstatat(AT_FDCWD, "/snap/core/current/usr/share/locale/POSIX/LC_MESSAGES/snappy.mo", 0xc42007eac8, 0) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
...
newfstatat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/share/locale-langpack/POSIX/LC_MESSAGES/snappy.mo", 0xc42007eb98, 0) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
...
newfstatat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/share/locale/POSIX/LC_MESSAGES/snappy.mo", 0xc42007ec68, 0) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
...
newfstatat(AT_FDCWD, "/snap/core/current/usr/share/locale-langpack/POSIX/LC_MESSAGES/snappy.mo", 0xc42007ed38, 0) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
...
newfstatat(AT_FDCWD, "/snap/core/current/usr/share/locale/POSIX/LC_MESSAGES/snappy.mo", 0xc42007ee08, 0) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
...
newfstatat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/share/locale-langpack/POSIX/LC_MESSAGES/snappy.mo", 0xc42007eed8, 0) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
...
newfstatat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/share/locale/POSIX/LC_MESSAGES/snappy.mo", 0xc42007efa8, 0) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
...
openat(AT_FDCWD, "", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
...
newfstatat(AT_FDCWD, "/snap/ubuntu-core-vm/7/meta/hooks", 0xc42007ff18, 0) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
...
access("/etc/ld.so.nohwcap", F_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
...
access("/etc/ld.so.preload", R_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
...
access("/etc/ld.so.nohwcap", F_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
...
access("/etc/ld.so.nohwcap", F_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
...
access("/etc/ld.so.preload", R_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
...
open("/var/lib/snapd/lib/gl/tls/x86_64/libtinfo.so.5", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
...
stat("/var/lib/snapd/lib/gl/tls/x86_64", 0x7ffd3d5191f0) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
...
open("/var/lib/snapd/lib/gl/tls/libtinfo.so.5", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
...
open("/var/lib/snapd/lib/gl/x86_64/libtinfo.so.5", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
...
stat("/var/lib/snapd/lib/gl/x86_64", 0x7ffd3d5191f0) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
...
open("/var/lib/snapd/lib/gl/libtinfo.so.5", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
...
open("/var/lib/snapd/lib/gl32/tls/x86_64/libtinfo.so.5", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
...
stat("/var/lib/snapd/lib/gl32/tls/x86_64", 0x7ffd3d5191f0) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
...
open("/var/lib/snapd/lib/gl32/tls/libtinfo.so.5", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
...
open("/var/lib/snapd/lib/gl32/x86_64/libtinfo.so.5", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
...
stat("/var/lib/snapd/lib/gl32/x86_64", 0x7ffd3d5191f0) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
...
open("/var/lib/snapd/lib/gl32/libtinfo.so.5", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
...
open("/var/lib/snapd/void/tls/x86_64/libtinfo.so.5", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
...
stat("/var/lib/snapd/void/tls/x86_64", 0x7ffd3d5191f0) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
...
open("/var/lib/snapd/void/tls/libtinfo.so.5", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
...
stat("/var/lib/snapd/void/tls", 0x7ffd3d5191f0) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
...
open("/var/lib/snapd/void/x86_64/libtinfo.so.5", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
...
stat("/var/lib/snapd/void/x86_64", 0x7ffd3d5191f0) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
...
open("/var/lib/snapd/void/libtinfo.so.5", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
...
open("/snap/ubuntu-core-vm/7/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/tls/x86_64/libtinfo.so.5", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
...
stat("/snap/ubuntu-core-vm/7/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/tls/x86_64", 0x7ffd3d5191f0) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
...
open("/snap/ubuntu-core-vm/7/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/tls/libtinfo.so.5", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
...
stat("/snap/ubuntu-core-vm/7/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/tls", 0x7ffd3d5191f0) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
...
open("/snap/ubuntu-core-vm/7/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/x86_64/libtinfo.so.5", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
...
stat("/snap/ubuntu-core-vm/7/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/x86_64", 0x7ffd3d5191f0) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
...
open("/snap/ubuntu-core-vm/7/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtinfo.so.5", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
...
open("tls/x86_64/libtinfo.so.5", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
...
open("tls/libtinfo.so.5", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
...
open("x86_64/libtinfo.so.5", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
...
open("libtinfo.so.5", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
...
open("/snap/ubuntu-core-vm/7/lib/tls/x86_64/libtinfo.so.5", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
...
stat("/snap/ubuntu-core-vm/7/lib/tls/x86_64", 0x7ffd3d5191f0) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
...
open("/snap/ubuntu-core-vm/7/lib/tls/libtinfo.so.5", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
...
stat("/snap/ubuntu-core-vm/7/lib/tls", 0x7ffd3d5191f0) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
...
open("/snap/ubuntu-core-vm/7/lib/x86_64/libtinfo.so.5", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
...
stat("/snap/ubuntu-core-vm/7/lib/x86_64", 0x7ffd3d5191f0) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
...
open("/snap/ubuntu-core-vm/7/lib/libtinfo.so.5", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
...
open("/snap/ubuntu-core-vm/7/usr/lib/tls/x86_64/libtinfo.so.5", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
...
stat("/snap/ubuntu-core-vm/7/usr/lib/tls/x86_64", 0x7ffd3d5191f0) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
...
open("/snap/ubuntu-core-vm/7/usr/lib/tls/libtinfo.so.5", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
...
stat("/snap/ubuntu-core-vm/7/usr/lib/tls", 0x7ffd3d5191f0) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
...
open("/snap/ubuntu-core-vm/7/usr/lib/x86_64/libtinfo.so.5", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
...
stat("/snap/ubuntu-core-vm/7/usr/lib/x86_64", 0x7ffd3d5191f0) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
...
open("/snap/ubuntu-core-vm/7/usr/lib/libtinfo.so.5", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
...
open("/snap/ubuntu-core-vm/7/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/tls/x86_64/libtinfo.so.5", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
...
stat("/snap/ubuntu-core-vm/7/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/tls/x86_64", 0x7ffd3d5191f0) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
...
open("/snap/ubuntu-core-vm/7/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/tls/libtinfo.so.5", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
...
stat("/snap/ubuntu-core-vm/7/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/tls", 0x7ffd3d5191f0) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
...
open("/snap/ubuntu-core-vm/7/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/x86_64/libtinfo.so.5", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
...
stat("/snap/ubuntu-core-vm/7/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/x86_64", 0x7ffd3d5191f0) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
...
open("/var/lib/snapd/lib/gl/tls/libdl.so.2", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
...
open("/var/lib/snapd/lib/gl/libdl.so.2", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
...
open("/var/lib/snapd/lib/gl32/tls/libdl.so.2", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
...
open("/var/lib/snapd/lib/gl32/libdl.so.2", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
...
open("/var/lib/snapd/void/libdl.so.2", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
...
open("/snap/ubuntu-core-vm/7/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
...
open("tls/x86_64/libdl.so.2", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
...
open("tls/libdl.so.2", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
...
open("x86_64/libdl.so.2", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
...
open("libdl.so.2", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC)  = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
...
open("/snap/ubuntu-core-vm/7/lib/libdl.so.2", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
...
open("/snap/ubuntu-core-vm/7/usr/lib/libdl.so.2", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
...
open("/var/lib/snapd/lib/gl/tls/libc.so.6", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
...
open("/var/lib/snapd/lib/gl/libc.so.6", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
...
open("/var/lib/snapd/lib/gl32/tls/libc.so.6", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
...
open("/var/lib/snapd/lib/gl32/libc.so.6", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
...
open("/var/lib/snapd/void/libc.so.6", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
...
open("/snap/ubuntu-core-vm/7/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
...
open("tls/x86_64/libc.so.6", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
...
open("tls/libc.so.6", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
...
open("x86_64/libc.so.6", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
...
open("libc.so.6", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC)   = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
...
open("/snap/ubuntu-core-vm/7/lib/libc.so.6", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
...
open("/snap/ubuntu-core-vm/7/usr/lib/libc.so.6", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
...
open("/usr/lib/locale/locale-archive", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
...
open("/usr/share/locale/locale.alias", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
...
open("/usr/lib/locale/en_GB.UTF-8/LC_IDENTIFICATION", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
...
open("/usr/lib/locale/en_GB.utf8/LC_IDENTIFICATION", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
...
open("/usr/lib/locale/en_GB/LC_IDENTIFICATION", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
...
open("/usr/lib/locale/en.UTF-8/LC_IDENTIFICATION", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
...
open("/usr/lib/locale/en.utf8/LC_IDENTIFICATION", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
...
open("/usr/lib/locale/en/LC_IDENTIFICATION", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
...
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, NULL, [], 8)  = 0
--- SIGSEGV {si_signo=SIGSEGV, si_code=SI_KERNEL, si_addr=0} ---
+++ killed by SIGSEGV (core dumped) +++
```

### References

- https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/snaps-to-develop-a-web-kiosk-on-ubuntu-core-using-wayland/6424
- https://developer.ubuntu.com/core/examples/snaps-on-mir

Answer (score 0):

Try running this command via strace

```
sudo apt install strace
sudo strace ubuntu-core-vm init edge
```

Keep in mind that strace is very verbose.

Look for anything suspicious before a segfault, as this may lead you to the source of the problem.

Also you can use `gdb` along withe core dump to analyze it.

Read about it here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8305866/how-do-i-analyze-a-programs-core-dump-file-with-gdb-when-it-has-command-line-pa

From your strace it seems that its' a snap package. But there are only beta and edge versions available:

```
sudo snap install ubuntu-core-vm
error: snap "ubuntu-core-vm" is not available on stable but is available to install on the
       following channels:

       beta       snap install --beta ubuntu-core-vm
       edge       snap install --edge ubuntu-core-vm

       Please be mindful pre-release channels may include features not completely tested or
       implemented. Get more information with 'snap info ubuntu-core-vm'.
```

So you should rather report a bug in this snap to its developers.

Comment: I have added the strace output. A bunch of "No such file or directory" messages may suggest missing dependencies(?)

Comment: strace will always show many "not found" messages, when the program "tries" to access certain files and dirs, but it doesn't necessarily mean that this is an actual problem. However your strace shows really nothing more except these errors, so indeed this might indicate the problem. Isn't ubuntu-core-vm snap a beta version? If so, it looks like a bug. And I can tell from `snap install ubuntu-core-vm` that `snap "ubuntu-core-vm" is not available on stable`, there are only beta and edge versions available. So maybe you've just found a bug in this package. You should probably report it to its dev